# Is it possible to enqueue a script from a widget method (of extended WP_Widget object)?

Tags: widgets, hooks, wp-enqueue-script

I am creating a widget plugin that a user could potentially use multiple iterations of the widget multiple times on a single widget-area / multiple widget-areas on a single page. Because of its functionality there will be differing widget-level variables that I will need to individually pass from PHP to JavaScript to take action on (via jQuery). I have used a `$widget_id` to wrap around the widget which works fine HTML-wise.

However I am having trouble passing the information to JavaScript -- at least when attempting to use `wp_localize_script` to pass info to the JavaScript file. My attempt to accomplish this was done by adding the action-hook to enqueue the JavaScript in the widget method. Unfortunately it appears that I can't even get the JavaScript to be enqueued from there, let alone am able to pass it information!

Here's what I have:

```
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {
   private $widget_id;
   private $variable; 
   private $plugin_location;

  function my_widget() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'My Widget Plugin');
    $this->plugin_location = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
  }

  function widget($args, $instance) {   
    $this->widget_id="widget-".time().rand(1,100).rand(1,100); //make a unique id for widget, i know there are probably better ways to do this... but this works for now...
    extract( $args );
    $this->variable = $instance['variable'];
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'plugin_scripts' ));
    echo '<div id="' . $this->widget_id . '">';
    ...
    create & output widget
    ..
    echo '</div>';
   }

   ... irrelevant widget administration functions ...
  public function plugin_scripts(){
    //here we set up & pass relevant information specific to EACH INDIVIDUAL widget (can have multiple in a single widget-area) for jQuery to execute functions & methods on to the JavaScript file
    $widget_info_to_pass = array(
      "widget_id"  =>  $this->widget_id,
      "variables"  =>  $this->variables
    );

    wp_register_script( 'my-site-script'.$this->widget_id, $this->plugin_location . "js/my.js", array('jquery'),'1.2.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-site-script'.$this->widget_id );
    wp_localize_script('my-site-script'.$this->widget_id, 'php_params', $widget_id_to_pass);
  }      

}

  add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("my_widget");'));
```

This doesn't enqueue the script, I am fairly certain because widget doesn't fire until after `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook has come and gone.

Important to note: **it appears that to use `wp_localize_script` you have to call the function before wp_head.**

To that note, I tried most of the hooks and was unable to even have the script enqueue at all let alone enqueue before `wp_head`. If I could even get the widget method to enqueue a script I can somehow manually add embedded JavaScript defining the information for each widget instance (maybe an associative array?) - but I can't get it to enqueue any scripts at all.

Is it possible to enqueue a script from the widget method of the extended `WP_Widget` object or am I fighting an unwinnable battle here? Are the other ways to do this that I am missing?

------------------- UPDATE ---------------------

I updated it using your advice like such:

```
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {
   private $widget_id;
   private $variable; 
   private $plugin_location;

  function my_widget() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'My Widget Plugin');
    $this->plugin_location = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
  }

  function widget($args, $instance) {   
    $this->widget_id="widget-".time().rand(1,100).rand(1,100); //make a unique id for widget, i know there are probably better ways to do this... but this works for now...
    extract( $args );
    $this->variable = $instance['variable'];
   //here we set up & pass relevant information specific to EACH INDIVIDUAL widget (can have multiple in a single widget-area) for jQuery to execute functions & methods on to the javascript file
    $widget_info_to_pass = array(
      "widget_id"  =>  $this->widget_id,
      "variable"  =>  $this->variable
    );
    wp_register_script( 'my-site-script'.$this->widget_id, $this->plugin_location . "js/my.js", array('jquery'),'1.2.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-site-script'.$this->widget_id );
    wp_localize_script('my-site-script'.$this->widget_id, 'php_params', $widget_id_to_pass);
    echo '<div id="' . $this->widget_id . '">';
    ...
    create & output widget
    ..
    echo '</div>';
   }

   ... irrelevant widget administration methods ...

}

  add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("my_widget");'));
```

To make sure I am being passed the proper info, I made my.js contain the following:

```
widget_id = php_params.widget_id;
variable = php_params.variable;
console.log(widget_id + "---" + variable);
```

Unfortunately it only outputs to the console the FINAL `widget_id` and variable three times.

Any reason why this happens? Any idea how to make it output the proper iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not true that you have to use `wp_localize_script` before the wp_head**.

Since 3.3 you can use `wp_enqueue_script` in the body of the document (i.e. in a widget or shortcode callback) and the script is loaded in the *footer*.

Here's a skeleton class I've used for adding variables for each instance of a widget to an array and then using `wp_localize_script` to add that entire array to the document. This loads the script, and the variables in the footer.

First *register* your script on the `init` hook.

```
class my_widget extends WP_Widget {

  static $variables=array();

  function my_widget() {
      //initialiser function
  }

  function widget($args, $instance) {   
     //Display widget

     //Then make sure our options will be added in the footer
     add_action('wp_footer', array(__CLASS__, 'add_options_to_script'));

     //Enqueue the script (registered on init)
     wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script');

     //Add the data to the (static) class variable `$variables`, using the widget ID.
     $id = $args['widget_id'];
     self::$variables[$id] = 'my variable for this instance'
   }

   //... irrelevant widget administration functions ...

  function add_options_to_script(){
       //If there is data to add, add it
       if(!empty(self::$widget_cal))
            wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'my_var', self::$variables);   
  }      

}

  add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("my_widget");'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` has already happened. enqueue the script directly in your widget function and output it in the footer.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? (example, maybe?) thanks.

Comment: move everything in the `plugin_scripts` function up to the `widget` function to replace where you call `add_action` to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. your javascript will be output in the footer instead of head.

Comment: gracias lemme give it a go

Comment: Milo - see my update... it 1/2 works --- it outputs to the log the information of the last generated widget 3x.

Comment: @setterGetter - it's because `php_params` isn't unique. you'll have to set a unique object for each localize call. there's probably also a way you can enqueue a single script to handle all your widgets, rather than creating a dynamic script handle the way you are now.

Comment: Yeah, my thoughts were to add each array to an object - then when all of the widgets have been completed pass a single localize object that contains that array. I tried adding that to the destructor class but that didn't work...

Comment: Let me backtrack a drop. If I var_dump the array it dumps out an array of arrays containing each widget-id and variable... but I cannot enqueue from the destructor...